# Bootstrap toggle alert-success

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am gathering data from a controller and placing it into a session variable called: message. I then pass message to the associated cshtml (Razor) page to a div with the alert-success class. The issue I have is not knowing how to only toggle the message when I click the save button. Razor code attached.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<p id="divConfirmationMessage" class="success-message message no-display">
      <span style="width:50px;" class="fl">
          <span class="icon successGreen"></span>        
  <div class="alert alert-success"><span> @Session["message"]</span></div>
      </span>
      <span class="icon close" style="padding-left:20px" id="spnReserveAcctCloseIcon"></span>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Razor's @if conditional

```
@if (@Session["message"] != null)
{
    <p id="divConfirmationMessage" class="success-message message no-display">
        <span style="width:50px;" class="fl">
            <span class="icon successGreen"></span>        
            <div class="alert alert-success"><span>@Session["message"]</span></div>
        </span>
        <span class="icon close" style="padding-left:20px" id="spnReserveAcctCloseIcon"></span>
    </p>
}
```